# How to select names from table that have the same id as a specific data in another table

Tags: mysql

First table named courses

| id | course_name | course_description | cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Python | Python is...etc | ScTh01 |
| 2 | Accounting | Accounting is...etc | BACC01 |
| 3 | Java | Java is...etc | ScTh01 |
| 4 | Fashion | Fashion is...etc | BFSC01 |

Second table named categories

| id | cat_name | cat_description | cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Business | Business is...etc | BACC01 |
| 2 | Health | Health is...etc | BSHP01 |
| 3 | Science | Science is...etc | ScTh01 |
| 4 | Art | Art is...etc | BSAR01 |

I want to be able to get all the courses from the table 'courses' that have the same cat_id as a specific category's cat_id in the 'categories' table.
So basically I want to be able to call each course according to or under its category in the 'categories' table

I have tried

```
$query='SELECT courses.course_name 
        FROM courses 
        INNER JOIN categories ON courses.cat_id=categories.cat_id 
        WHERE courses.cat_id = "ScTh01"';
```

Please any help on how I can accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  It sounds like you're just looking for the `WHERE` keyword in SQL, which would be covered in any introductory tutorial.  Please elaborate on the specific attempt you've made and the specific problem you've encountered.

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is connecting directly to MySQL and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I am new to php and trying to build a school management sytem, I have tried  "$query='SELECT courses.course_name FROM courses INNER JOIN categories ON courses.cat_id=categories.cat_id WHERE courses.cat_id = "ScTh01"';"

Comment: @irah22: And what isn't working as expected in that attempt?  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] with `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements to set up the tables, and your `SELECT` statement demonstrating the result?

Comment: Your query should work, but why do you need the join? Just use `SELECT course_name FROM courses WHERE cat_id = "ScTh01"`

Comment: You would need the join if you wanted to select the category by its name, e.g. `WHERE categories.cat_name = 'Science'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `WHERE` to `AND`

```
$query='SELECT courses.course_name 
        FROM courses 
        INNER JOIN categories ON courses.cat_id=categories.cat_id 
        AND courses.cat_id = "ScTh01"';
```